# How to properly handle params + POST params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the route `post '/blogs/:blog_id/posts', 'posts#create'` which points to the `PostsController#create`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:url)
  end
end
```

Because `blog_id` is not part of the `post_params`, rails will raise a MySQL error saying that the `blog_id` is missing in the `Post.new`. How can I handle this? What is the proper way to handle it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the "railsy" pattern is:

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
@post = @blog.posts.build(post_params)

if @post.save
....
```